# Form in popup, disabling child click to close blocking checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a popup window that has a form in it and to stop the popped up div clicks from closing the window I've used:

```
$(".popup").click(function () {
    $(".popup").css("display", "none");
}).children().click(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

However this works perfectly except with checkboxes whereby it disables checking them.

Is there any way around this?

popup is an overlay, then popupInner holds the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your code with this:

```
$(".popup").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) $(this).hide();
});
```

It would hide the popup only if clicked on the element with class popup and not its children, it would also keep the functionality of the children intact.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Will mark this as the answer when I can.